# Find HTML EDITOR for develop html 5

Tags: eclipse, html

I used eclipse 3.8 to develop HTML 5 Android Application.But i need to find a specific HTML and JavaScript editor to write html 5.I install several HTML editors that goes with eclipse.But it does not  show  on eclipse IDE.

Comment: Why do you want to use Eclipse for HTML/JavaScript development?

Comment: to develop android application using phone gap(HTML5)

Answer (score 0):

use BlueVoda or 90 second website builder software. If u have still problems to your answer, there is a tutor on 90 second website builder

Answer (score 0):

Give [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) a shot. Not specifically HTML5/Javascript, but having used Eclipse/Dreamweaver/WebStorm, it provides superior functionality and usability. Plus, it's highly extensible and free to use as a demo! There's even a plugin for my Jade templates! Woo hoo!